# format data using .map and .filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

i got a following type of result from the data base when i fetch database. i have tried many thing and serch google but could't found anything. please help me with this. thank you.

```
{ metaData:
   [ { name: 'ID' },
     { name: 'NAME' },
     { name: 'LED_ID' },
     { name: 'LED_ORG_ID' },
     { name: 'COMPANY_ADD' },
     { name: 'STATE_CODE' },
     { name: 'CIN_NO' } ],
  rows:
   [ [ 1,
       'company name',
       2481,
       '161',
       'address ',
       '27',
       'number' ],
     [ 2,
       'company name2',
       2581,
       '164',
       'address 2',
       '27',
       'number2' ]
}
}
```

I am trying to achieve below formatted data

```
{
 data:[
 {
  ID:1,
  NAME:'company name',
  LED_ID:2481,
  LED_ORG_ID: '161',
  COMPANY_ADD:'address',
  STATE_CODE:'27',
  CIN_NO:'number'
},
 {
  ID:2,
  NAME:'company name 2',
  LED_ID:2581,
  LED_ORG_ID: '164',
  COMPANY_ADD:'address 2',
  STATE_CODE:'27',
  CIN_NO:'number 2'
}
]
}
```

Comment: use `.map` and `.filter` array methods as required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = {
  metaData: [{
      name: 'ID'
    },
    {
      name: 'NAME'
    },
    {
      name: 'LED_ID'
    },
    {
      name: 'LED_ORG_ID'
    },
    {
      name: 'COMPANY_ADD'
    },
    {
      name: 'STATE_CODE'
    },
    {
      name: 'CIN_NO'
    }
  ],
  rows: [
    [1,
      'company name',
      2481,
      '161',
      'address ',
      '27',
      'number'
    ],
    [2,
      'company name2',
      2581,
      '164',
      'address 2',
      '27',
      'number2'
    ]
  ]
}

let transform = (meta, item) => {
  return meta.map((a, i) => ({
    [a.name]: item[i]
  }))
}

let result = data.rows.map(i => transform(data.metaData, i))

console.log(result.map(i => Object.assign({}, ...i)))
```

It can be better...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array.map()` and `Object.fromEntires()`:

```js
let data = { metaData:
   [ { name: 'ID' },
     { name: 'NAME' },
     { name: 'LED_ID' },
     { name: 'LED_ORG_ID' },
     { name: 'COMPANY_ADD' },
     { name: 'STATE_CODE' },
     { name: 'CIN_NO' } ],
  rows:
   [ [ 1,
       'company name',
       2481,
       '161',
       'address ',
       '27',
       'number' ],
     [ 2,
       'company name2',
       2581,
       '164',
       'address 2',
       '27',
       'number2' ]
   ]
}

let result = data.rows.map(
        entry => Object.fromEntries(
            entry.map((x, i) => [data.metaData[i].name, x])
        )
    )

console.log(result)
```

EDIT: The outer `map` transforms `rows` so there will be two objects returned. The inner one transforms all the values into format like `["ID", 1]`. That array of arrays is passed as an argument into `Object.fromEntries` which creates a new object based on those pairs.

Comment: @clydecorrea modified my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` in conjunction with `flatMap` and `reduce`:

```js
const metaData = [{name:'ID'},{name:'NAME'},{name:'LED_ID'},{name:'LED_ORG_ID'},{name:'COMPANY_ADD'},{name:'STATE_CODE'},{name:'CIN_NO'}];
const rows = [[1,'company name',2481,'161','address ','27','number'],[2,'company name2',2581,'164','address 2','27','number2']];

const res = rows.flatMap(e => e.map((f, i) => ({ [metaData[i].name]: f })).reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, ...c }), {}));

console.log(res);
```

More performant solution thanks to Mark Meyer:

```
const res = rows.map(e => e.reduce((a, c, i) => ({ ...a, ...{ [metaData[i].name]: c }}), {});
```

Comment: What's the point of `flatMap()` here? You could just use `map()` and support a wider set of users with the same results.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Try changing flatMap to map - the reduction doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, works in the snippet here and in node. Also you can save a loop: `const res = rows.map(e => e.reduce((a, c, i) => ({ ...a, ...{[metaData[i].name]:c} }), {}));`

Comment: My bad, wasn't thinking - thanks, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the keys first and then map the object from the entries.

```js
var data = { metaData: [{ name: 'ID' }, { name: 'NAME' }, { name: 'LED_ID' }, { name: 'LED_ORG_ID' }, { name: 'COMPANY_ADD' }, { name: 'STATE_CODE' }, { name: 'CIN_NO' }], rows: [[1, 'company name', 2481, '161', 'address ', '27', 'number'], [2, 'company name2', 2581, '164', 'address 2', '27', 'number2']] },
    keys = data.metaData.map(({ name }) => name),
    result = { data: data.rows.map(a => Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k, i) => [k, a[i]]))) };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```